# html response works well but Json response doesn't

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have a controller function which responds with json response to the ajax call. But i always get **undefined** in my success data if i respond with json response.
and it network tab also it doesn't show any response. But if i response with html. It works fine and it also appears in network tab. I have implemented it many times it was fine on other pages but this one cause the issue.

Here is my ajax

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/resume_upload',
  type: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  },
  mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
  data: form_data,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data.msg);
  },
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(xhr);
    alert(xhr);
  }
});
```

Here is my server response

```
if($candidate->save()){
  return response()->json(['msg'=>'hello']);// doesn't work                            
  //echo "hello"; //works
}
else{
  return  response()->json(['msg'=>'No hello']); //doesn't work
}
```

Comment: Are you setting application/json header - and what if you use getJSON ?

Comment: is your url right? looks like it should be `/resume_upload.php`

Comment: No i don't @mplungjan ,

Comment: This is framework route so there is no necessity to set .php @abc123

Comment: Add `header("Content-type: application/json")`

Comment: I did set `contentType: "application/json",` in my ajax call. Still the error exists